# hide one image and visible another image when i clicked the button in android

Tags: android, imagebutton, visible

this is my code;

```
ib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
ib1.setImageResource(i);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fail",1000).show();
Thread.sleep(10000);
ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bck_image1);
```

please give some suggestion as soon as possible.

Comment: what u want to do ? on click do u want to hide 1 image and want to show another ? and on again click want to show first one and want to hide 2nd ?

Comment: more description for ur question ... what u want actually ?

Comment: I want when i clicked the button,ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple) is show first and then this apple image is hide after 100 millisecond and i want to show ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange) this orange image i want to show..this all happen with in one click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below snippet might be helpful

```
ib1.setImageResource(i);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fail",1000).show();
android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bck_image1);
    }},1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for changing visibility of imagebuttons on button click

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
{
    //For changing visibility
    ib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ib1.setVisibility(View.GONE); //or View.INVISIBLE - as per youur requirement.
    //For changing image resources
    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
});
```

Comment: also use `Handler.postDelayed` for making wait instead of `Thread.sleep(10000);` which freeze UI Thread

Comment: I want when i clicked the button,ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple) is show first and then this apple image is hide after 100 millisecond and i want to show ib1.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange) this orange image i want to show..this all happen with in one click

Comment: @yogi : and what is current behavior of application ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K :Card flip game

Answer (score 0):

Use **`setVisibility(int)`** function .  You can use

for Hiding use

```
image.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE)
```

and to make it visible use

```
image.setVisibility(INVISIBLE)
```

check the below link for more details
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)